# Output of Command not being stored and failing Regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, regular-expression

I'm trying to write a git post-push hook that runs `yarn prettier --check ./src` for my react app, to enforce good code format. I thought that I could store the output of the command and use regex to see if a specific error appears.

What I'm trying to run as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd frontend/
VAR=$(yarn prettier --check ./src)
if [[ $VAR =~ .*"error Command failed with exit code 1."* ]]; then
        echo "Failed to run prettier before push."
else
        echo "Passed prettier"
fi
```

What the output shows:

```
[warn] src/order/orderApi.ts
[warn] Code style issues found in the above file. Forgot to run Prettier?
error Command failed with exit code 1.                                                                          
Passed prettier
```

*I purposely put an error that I knew prettier would catch in the orderApi.tx*

I thought that when you store the output you do `Variable=$(command insert)`
I've checked the following tutorials, but I haven't gotten anywhere:

- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash/
- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-string-comparison

Comment: Since the exit code is `1` you can use simply run `yarn prettier --check ./src` without assign its output to a variable and you'll have to check the exit code by using `$?` in your if, like this: `if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then ...`

Comment: Btw, your **if statement** did not work because the error message is redirected to stderr, so if you want to use the variable then you can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` like this: `VAR=$(yarn prettier --check ./src 2>&1)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I alter the script to --> `yarn prettier --check ./src
if [[$? -eq  1 ]]; then
        echo "Failed to run prettier before push."
else
        echo "Passeed Prettier"
fi` it will still give me `./prettierCheck.sh: line 4: [[1: command not found
Passeed Prettier`

Comment: If I change to `VAR=$(yarn prettier --check ./src 2>&1)` it will still run the command and check, but will still say `line 4: [[1: command not found Passeed Prettier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a string comparison you can check the exit code of your command by using this:

```bash
yarn prettier --check ./src
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Failed to run prettier before push."
else
        echo "Passed prettier"
fi
```

**Important:**  Add a space between the square brackets and the statement: `[[ $? -eq 1 ]];`.

---

About the string comparison your variable actually never has the error message because the yarn errors are redirected to `stderr` and you are assigning only the `stdout` of the command. So if you want to assign the errors/stderr as well then you redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```bash
VAR=$(yarn prettier --check ./src 2>&1)

# or: if [[ $VAR =~ "error Command failed with exit code 1." ]]; then
if [[ $VAR =~ .*"error Command failed with exit code 1."* ]]; then
        echo "Failed to run prettier before push."
else
        echo "Passed prettier"
fi
```

Or redirect only `stderr` with:

```bash
VAR=$(yarn prettier --check ./src 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't know the spacing mattered as much as it does. Thank you very much for the clarification and help. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours.

Comment: @RogueGingerz You're welcome! And if  this answer helped you most please accept it by clicking the tick mark (✔).  That's how you can say "thanks" here on the stack exchange sites :D

Comment: Ooops, sorry about that. Thought I accepted it last night.